# Is exponential function in a C*-algebra injective on self-adjoint elements?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, the usual exponential function from $A$ into $A$. Is it true that if $x\ne y\in A$, $x^*=x$, $y^*=y$, then $\exp(x)\ne\exp(y)$?

Comment: Can you show that $\ln(\exp(x))=x$ for such an $x$?

Comment: Do you mean $\ln x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x-1)^n$?  No, I have no intuition here. Is it easy to prove?

Comment: Do you have a functional calculus where $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$? I'm just not sure what facts are known to you.

Comment: Calculus? You can think that nothing is known to me, but the definitions of C*-algebra and $\exp$. :)

Comment: Christian Remling answered this question in MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185536/is-exponential-function-in-a-c-algebra-injective-on-self-adjoint-elements Thanks to all!

Comment: So you know how to take the $n$-th positive root of $e^{x}$ at this level? Okay.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed not good. People read this, some of them are students, it's not nice to feed them hints. Can anybody give an accurate answer (as far as I understand, spectral theorem must be mentioned anyway)? -- I will accept it, and everybody will be satisfied.